# How do I get my missing Stellar USDC?

Tags: transactions

My apology for asking such a question. Just now I purchased Stellar USDC on Airtm, through MoonPay. It asks for a destination wallet, so I copied it from Airtm (which now I know it is a public wallet). Long story short, my funds are in the public wallet (I checked it on Stellar Expert). How can I get my funds back?